# How to make outlook email signature responsive

Tags: email, responsive-design, outlook, signature

I'm setting up a new email signature for my client which needs to be responsive .

I tried out one layout which includes div , tables etc which works out good on desktops but not on mobiles .

Below is one such sample but the email appears as same is desktop & mobile with the cells / divs shifting one under the other .

As a part of my research , i tried using this email boilerplate which ended up in the same way . - https://github.com/seanpowell/Email-Boilerplate

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <table cellspacing=0><tr><td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: #fff; background-color: orange; width: 250px; height: 100px; padding: 3px; vertical-align: top">
<![endif]-->
<div style="float: left; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: #fff; background-color: orange; width: 250px; height: 100px; padding: 3px; vertical-align: top">
    <strong>Administrator</strong><br>Phone {qwfqwfcqwdqwfqfgqwfqwbfjqnwjkfqnwjfbqiwnf qwnfiquwnqwnfiqnwifjnqwfinqwifnqwjinfqjiwnfijqwnf}<br>Email <a href="mailto:{E-mail}" style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;">{qwfqwfqwcqwfqwfqwfdqwcrqwrqwcrqwrqwrcqwrxqwrqwcxqrwqxrqwxqwx}</a>
</div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </td><td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: #fff; background-color: red; width: 250px; height: 100px; padding: 3px; vertical-align: top">
<![endif]-->
<div style="float: left; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; color: #fff; background-color: red; width: 250px; height: 100px; padding: 3px; vertical-align: top">
    <strong>qwfqwfqwdqw fqwfqwfqwdfqwdqwfqwfqwdqwdqwdqw</strong> ​
</div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>    
</td></tr></table>
    <![endif]-->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/623y57p1/1/

Have a look at the demo i made . This is responsive in browsers , but not in outlook .

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample code that works with Outlook. The two columns of this email footer will display side-by-side if the viewing window is wider than 580px. If it goes below that width, it will revert to two stacked columns. You can set the width breakpoint by adjusting `<td width="290">`.

```
<table align="center" role="contentinfo" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="100%" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td width="290" style="direction: ltr !important; display: inline-block;">
      Column A
    </td>
    <td width="290" style="direction: ltr !important; display: inline-block;">
      Column B
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please keep in mind a few caveats:

- Outlook 2007-2019 does not support responsive email. There is no support for  `@media` queries.
- The width for the `table` must be set to `<table width="100%">`.
- The width for the table cells to 290 because the maximum width for an Outlook viewing window is 580px.
- You can turn off `<table border="1">` It's on for demonstration purposes.
- `<table role="contentinfo">` supports screen readers. Please leave it to help visually impaired users know about the structure of your email message.
- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/w0s4xmc0/60529/

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort . 

Few things to mention out . 

I used the above code in the email signature of outlook ( creating a new .htm file in (C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\email.htm ) . The signature appeared in the outlook signature button , which infact was good for me . 

1. Since we are giving table width = 100% , the table consumes the entire width of the email (i was able to resolve this by using max-width = 560px)

2 . For the view on mobile screens , They still dont come one under the other . they come side by side . 

 https://imgur.com/a/jR9L3iJ

Comment: Wait, @titus are you saying you didn’t follow my explicit instructions and now it doesn’t work? Did you try following what I told you to do?

Comment: Tried two methods infact . 

1 - I tried inserting the same table mentioned in your answer to the body of my email to see if it becomes responsive .

2 - I tried inserting it into the outlook email signature module by (rewriting the .htm signature ) . 

Both methods didnot output the result expected . Do let me know if there was any other way to test the code .

Comment: do let me know if there is any other way to test the code that you have given .

Comment: I also tried this, copying and pasting exactly the same code without any modification in my Outlook 2013. It didn't work. Table cells don't collapse and stay side-by-side.